# getting error while connecting to Microservices connecting to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, microservices

I am learning microservices and I have two classes `orderservice` and `paymentservice`. while I am running the code, it is running fine and successfully but when I am passing the data to database through `postman`, it is showing internal server error with console message in payment class like this

```
"Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: PAYMENT_TB.PAYMENT_TB index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 0 }', details={}}"
```

and in order class like this

```
"500 : "{"timestamp":"2022-02-24T11:12:46.925+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/payment/doPayment"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that there's already a record with `null` as the email. In other words, you already have a user without an email address.

The relevant documentation for this:

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.

> You can combine the unique constraint with the sparse index to filter these null values from the unique index and avoid the error.

[unique indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field)

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value.

In other words, a sparse index is ok with multiple documents all having `null` values.

[sparse indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/)